# Why does primefaces menuitem need a form?

Tags: forms, primefaces, menu, menuitem

Why does my menu in primefaces need a form around is? Is this the best way?

Form needed:

```
<h:form id="menuForm">
    <p:menu>
        <p:menuitem value="Simple Flow" action="simple-flow" ajax="false"/>
    </p:menu>
</h:form>
```

No form needed:

```
<p:menu>
    <p:menuitem value="Simple Flow" outcome="/simple-flow/simple-flow"/>
</p:menu>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A menu item with an outcome generates a plain html `a` tag with an href to a internal page (within the domain of the application). When clicked on, that produces a get request to the specified page. The url attribute does the same btw, but can be used to refer to external page, as can be seen by investigating the source of the [PrimeFaces menu showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml) This functionality does not need a form since no data needs to be send to the server.

The action attribute generates an `a` tag as well, but it will always need to send data to the server and be able to call a method on the server. (that is how the funtion of an action in general is defined in JSF). The menu item in this case has no functional hfref (it is "#") but has an onclick that via javascript (see the source of the showcase) either  does an ajax call (if specified) or full submit of the form. Since in both cases the form data needs to be send to the server a form is needed (that is how html works).

Yes, you can exclude sending other data by specifying process="@this" or maybe you don't have no data, but still the server needs to be aware of what takes place and the behaviour has to be consistent with the spec. And your example where you do not call a method on the server (there is no #{...}), is an optimization where you can now specify a direct page that was introduced in JSF 2. In jsf 1.2 you needed navigation rules for this. (see http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/)

So the behaviour you see in the ui might not be different but behind the scenes they are.